# How do I send a command from bash into a java program?

Tags: java, bash

So right now I am using `java -Xms${ram}M -Xmx${ram}M -jar craftbukkit.jar` to run the craftbukkit.jar.

What I want to do is send a command, like `stop` to the running server. It runs in the command line.

I have tried doing:

```
java -Xms${ram}M -Xmx${ram}M -jar craftbukkit.jar
stop
```

but that only executes `stop` after I type it in manually and the server program stops.

How can I get it to send the `stop` command to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
echo stop | java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar > /dev/null
```

Comment: Doesn't this send the `stop` command as soon as the server starts?